# Fetch is not returning data from Rails Controller

Tags: ajax, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, fetch

I'm using the fetch api to request data from my rails controller. The request getting to the controller and I'm successfully looking up some data from my database.

```
def show
    set_recipe
    @recipe.to_json
end
```

However, the fetch statement in my react component isn't setting the state object.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: null,
    };
}  

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/recipes/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
  }

render() {
    return(<div>{this.state.data}</div>)
  }
}
```

Thoughts?

UPDATE:  Using postman I realized that my component wasn't actually returning any json. I updated the controller code above to look like what you see below. After this postman started getting json responses. However, this didn't fix the fact that my component state was still null. I did some debugging in the chrome console and with the fetch was able to get a json from the server. This narrows it down to being an issue with how I'm using fetch inside the componentDidMount.

```
   def show
    set_recipe
    render(json: @recipe)
   end
```

UPDATE 2: RESOLVED

Got it working. I downloaded the react developer extension for chrome and I could see that this.state.data was actually getting set. But I was getting an error saying that react couldn't render an object. So I needed to add the .name to get the name string out of the json object. Then finally I was getting an error because this.state.data was initialized as a null and I guess the first time the component renders before mounting it hadn't yet set it to json and .name isn't a method that could be called from null. By initializing it to an empty string it worked, not sure why though. Below is the final component:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            recipe: ''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/recipes/1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(recipe => this.setState({ recipe }));
    }

    render() {
        return(<div>{this.state.recipe.name}</div>)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong in your code. How is the response looks like of fetch call I mean data?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what it needed to look like. See original post for more detail.

Controller:

```
   def show
    set_recipe
    render(json: @recipe)
   end
```

Component:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            recipe: ''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/recipes/1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(recipe => this.setState({ recipe }));
    }

    render() {
        return(<div>{this.state.recipe.name}</div>)
    }
}
```